# Zuora Payment Page Implementation

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

I have implemented Zuora Payment Pages for the latest version 6.3 which Zuora is calling payment pages 2.0.

I am able to successfully create the Payment Method. But the problem is callback for the payment pages.

I am trying to implement custom callback with the interface `zqu.PaymentPageCallbackController` provided by Zuora as I have to call a method in the another class and I have no clue to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<apex:page controller="zqu.PaymentPageCallbackController,AddNewCard" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.zqu__jquery_1_9_1}" />
        <script>  
        function callback() {
         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{!JSENCODE(callbackParameterString)}' );     
         console.log(obj);
         console.log(obj.refId);
        if(parent.processCallback) parent.processCallback('{!JSENCODE(callbackParameterString)}');
      }

  // Execute the callback when the document finishes loading
  var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
  $jq(function() {
    callback();
  });
</script>
<body style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);" />
```

I have modified this code to call the SuccessActions.

    
        
        function callback() {

```
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{!JSENCODE(callbackParameterString)}' );     
     console.log(obj);
     console.log(obj.refId);
     var pmId=obj.refId;
    if(parent.processCallback) parent.processCallback('{!JSENCODE(callbackParameterString)}');
      performSuccessActions(pmId, obj);
  }

  // Execute the callback when the document finishes loading
  var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
  $jq(function() {
    callback();
  });
</script>
 <apex:actionStatus startText="" stopText="" id="action" onstart="javascript:displayStatusModal()" onstop="javascript:closeStatusModal()" />
        <apex:actionFunction name="performSuccessActions" action="{!successActions}" rerender="buttons">
            <apex:param name="pmid" value="pmid" assignTo="{!pmId}" />
            <apex:param name="displayMessage" value="dispayMessage" assignTo="{!displayMessage}" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
<body style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);" />
```

this code is provided by Zuora any changes i make are not getting compiled.

Comment: I have posted the code for the visualforce page but it is not showing up the entire code.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understand your question properly all you have to do is to call another function once your action function is completed ?

If yes, then as you have mentioned that you need to call a method which is written in another class, just add an extensions to the class having your callback method and override its constructor. 
 Add this actionFunction.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callBack" action="{!callBackMethod}" />
```

and call this actionfunction from your current action function's oncomplete attribute.

Comment: If your problem is solved then, please mark this as a solution to your problem so it will be available for other having same issue.

Comment: It is not sovled.As we are not able to add extension  to the custom controller.

Comment: well in that case you can use Javascript remoting to solve this problem

Comment: I am trying to throw the  parameters to the parent window but the problem is parent window javascript function is not getting recognised.Any ideas on how to get this done.

Comment: You can access parent window javascript funcion by using window.parent.parentFunction(), syntax .. hope it will help you

Comment: Also you can call it from your current custom controller. All you have to do is to create a new method (intermediate method ) in your current controller and then call your callback method from this newly created intermediate  method and you can also pass parameter to your callback method exists in another class by using this intermediate method.

Comment: PaymentPageCallbackControlleris given by Zuora.It is a managed component..We cannot edit or implement like an interface.Reference:https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/CA_Commerce/F_Development_Resources/C_Component_Library/B_Global_Components/PaymentPage_Component/C_Use_Case%3A_Create_a_Payment_Page_Button

Comment: Can you call this method directly from Developer console by passing valid parameters ?